# Как передавать аргументы в скрипт в формате argName=value

Tags: bash, shell

Мне нужно при запуске скрипта передавать в него аргументы в формате -argName=value
и потом сохранять значения value для переменных с названием argName. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать.

Comment: Не оч понятно, как там было распаршено значение. Если можно распишите тут подробно как я могу при запуске скрипта передать ему значения с названием переменных, в которые они должны будут поместиться. 
./script.sh -startDate=2018-01 -endDate=2019-02 пример

Comment: ну там же написаны примеры. `-startDate) startDate="$2" ...`

Comment: а если вам надо определить **произвольные** переменные окружения, так определите их, вместо того, чтобы пытаться передать их аргументами.

Comment: дело в том, что у меня могут как отсутствовать, так и присутствовать переменные, не факт что все будут сразу и в хронологическом порядке

Comment: при чём тут порядок? аргументы перебираются в цикле. есть нужный аргумент: присваиваете значение переменной. нет — не присваиваете. но я вам уже написал, что, судя по вашим запросам, вам не аргументы для скрипта нужны, а переменные окружения.

Comment: `-*) varname=$(echo $1 | cut -c1-); varvalue="$2"; eval "$varname=$varvalue";` -- как-то так...